# Using $natural sort in pymongo - MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I understand that using the $natural sort in MongoDB can improve disk throughput as the cursor will read sequential records rather than jumping around.

However when I try to use this [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647962/how-to-quickly-fetch-all-documents-mongodb-pymongo) or follow the [Cursor.sort() Ref Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#return-natural-order) I get the following errors:

```
for t in collection.find({'raw.lang': 'en'}).sort( { $natural: 1 } ):
```

*Unsuprisingly gives a syntax error.*

```
for t in collection.find({'raw.lang': 'en'}).sort( { '$natural': 1 } ):
```

*Exception has occurred: TypeError
if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list*

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass array of sort keys as mentioned in the exception,

```
for t in collection.find({'raw.lang': 'en'}).sort([( '$natural', 1 )] ):
```

Comment: Actual working code used was:
for t in collection.find({'raw.lang': 'en'}).sort([( '$natural', 1 )] ):
NOTE the comma instead of colon.

Comment: ya, my bad. Updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, the comma and square brackets around $natural are different in pymongo than regular MongoDB queries. Thanks!